# Input redirection after program has started running

Tags: bash, pipe, io-redirection

Is there a way to use input redirection after the program has started?

For example I want to run a program, scrape some data from it, then use that data to push it + some static data (from a file) to std input:

```
1    ./Binary
2    Hello the open machine is: computer2
3    Which computer:command do you want to use:  
4    <<< "computer2:RunWaterPlants"
```

I want to redirect line 4 in using some program output from line 2.

I've tried [Keeping a bash script running along the program it has started, and sending the program input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3883051/keeping-a-bash-script-running-along-the-program-it-has-started-and-sending-the), but it will just continue with the program execution without waiting for my input.

I can't edit `./Binary`.

I found [Write to stdin of a running process using pipe](https://serverfault.com/questions/443297/write-to-stdin-of-a-running-process-using-pipe) and it works for what I'm asking, but I can't see the stdout when I run it with pipe.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out from [Writing to stdin of a process](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/385771/writing-to-stdin-of-a-process). Pretty much I started a fifo pipe and wrote to it and let it listen for input.